# Python File upload using opendrive api

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python script to upload file to opendrive using opendrive api. I am using `requests` library for handing REST. Now I'm stuck on file upload. The documentation for API for file upload is at   https://dev.opendrive.com/api/explorer/#!/upload/createUpload_file_chunk_post

I try to upload the file but I am getting various errors. I try to upload file by adding the code

`files = {'files': open('/Users/djangod/text.txt', 'rb')}` with post data. But I am getting various errors related to chunk size.

Comment: Could you supply more code so that your problem's context can be understood?

Comment: filehandle = {'file': open('screen.png', 'rb').read()}  
    uploadfile_link = '/v1/upload/upload_file_chunk.json'
    uploadfile_head_data = {'session_id': session_id, 'file_id':createfile_id, 'temp_location': templocation, 'chunk_offset': 0, 'chunk_size': 65536}
    uploadfile_req = requests.post(api_link+uploadfile_link, data=uploadfile_head_data, files = filehandle)